# mapbox gl fill-extrusion-height-transition not working

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I've been trying to use fill-extrusion-height with a transition, and it doesn't seem to be working. Other transitions (like fill-extrusion-height-opacity) are working.

Anyone bumped up against this or have any ideas? I've gone through the github issues for mapbox gl and it confirms extrusion height should be transitionable

Example of what's happening here: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/331073/

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoidGFkaXJhbWFuIiwiYSI6IktzUnNGa28ifQ.PY_hnRMhS94SZmIR2AIgug';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
    center: [-74.0066, 40.7135],
    zoom: 15.5,
    pitch: 45,
    bearing: -17.6,
    container: 'map'
});

$('button').click(function() {
map.setPaintProperty('3d-buildings', 'fill-extrusion-height', 75);
})

// The 'building' layer in the mapbox-streets vector source contains building-height
// data from OpenStreetMap.
map.on('load', function () {
    // Insert the layer beneath any symbol layer.
    var layers = map.getStyle().layers;

    var labelLayerId;
    for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
        if (layers[i].type === 'symbol' && layers[i].layout['text-field']) {
            labelLayerId = layers[i].id;
            break;
        }
    }

    map.addLayer({
        'id': '3d-buildings',
        'source': 'composite',
        'source-layer': 'building',
        'filter': ['==', 'extrude', 'true'],
        'type': 'fill-extrusion',
        'minzoom': 15,
        'paint': {
            'fill-extrusion-color': '#aaa',

            // use an 'interpolate' expression to add a smooth transition effect to the
            // buildings as the user zooms in
            'fill-extrusion-height': [
                "interpolate", ["linear"], ["zoom"],
                15, 0,
                15.05, ["get", "height"]
            ],
            'fill-extrusion-base': [
                "interpolate", ["linear"], ["zoom"],
                15, 0,
                15.05, ["get", "min_height"]
            ],
            'fill-extrusion-height-transition':{
                duration: 2000,
                delay: 0
            },
            'fill-extrusion-opacity': .6
        }
    }, labelLayerId);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it works fine. Your example is switching from a data-driven property to a constant, and *that* doesn't seem to be transitionable. But transitioning from one constant to another works, as you see in this slightly tweaked version of your code:

https://jsfiddle.net/tyf76u0d/2/

```
 $('button').click(function() {

        map.setPaintProperty('3d-buildings', 'fill-extrusion-height', Math.random()*250 + 50);

    })
```

Comment: Yes, that turned out to be the issue. According to mapbox, they don't support data driven transitions yet. Too bad. Thanks!

Comment: Thank a lot man! Either I missed it in documentation OR  they should mention it somewhere. I was wondering all the time why transitions are not working. Able to get it now that it doesn't work with data-driven style.